# How can I "override" deepcopy in Python?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, deep-copy

I'd like to override `__deepcopy__` for a given SQLAlchemy-mapped class such that it ignores any SQLA attributes but deepcopies everything else that's part of the class.

I'm not particularly familiar with overriding any of Python's built-in objects in particular but I've got some idea as to what I want.

Let's just make a very simple class `User` that's mapped using SQLA.

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self, user_id=None, name=None):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.name = name
```

I've used `dir()` to see, before and after mapping, what SQLAlchemy-specific attributes there are and I've found `_sa_class_manager` and `_sa_instance_state`.

`Questions`
Provided those are the only ones how would I ignore that when defining `__deepcopy__`?
Also, are there any attributes the SQLA injects into the mapped object?

---

(I asked this in a previous question (as an edit a few days after I selected an answer to the main question, though) but I think I missed the train there. Apologies for that.)

---

`Edit - Fixed code thanks to zifot's answer`

The only thing I got out of the Python docs is that you need to define deepcopy with `memo` as an extra argument. After a teensy bit of digging around I tried this out:

```
def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
    dpcpy = self.__class__()
    memo[id(self)] = dpcpy
    for attr in dir(self):
        if not attr.startswith('_'):
            value = getattr(self, attr)
            setattr(dpcpy, attr, copy.deepcopy(value, memo))
    return dpcpy
```

Then I created an instance of `User` as:

```
snake = User(913, 'Snake,S.')
```

After that, I tried a `deepcopy` operation as:

```
snake_dc = copy.deepcopy(snake)
```

...and `snake_dc` still has the SQLA attributes in it...

I'm all open to help, suggestions, etc.

Answer (score 2):

When (deep-)copying you should not be calling `__init__` but instead call `__new__`.

An example:

```
def __copy__(self):
    cls = self.__class__
    newobject = cls.__new__(cls)
    newobject.__dict__.update(self.__dict__)
    return newobject
```

Comment: +1 This is made clear by Rob Young's comment in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500718/what-is-the-right-way-to-override-the-copy-deepcopy-operations-on-an-object-in-p

Answer (score 1):

mavnn [is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036648/how-can-i-override-deepcopy-in-python/3037000#3037000). For example try change your init of User to:

```
def __init__(self, user_id = None, name = None):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.name = name
```

As for copying mapped instances, I recommend reading [this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlalchemy@googlegroups.com/msg10895.html)

Comment: Thanks. Changed the `__init__` for `User`, but unfortunately `snake_dc` seems to have the SQLA attributes intact :S

Comment: That's because User class is mapped and every new instance of it will have these attributes (in particular that created in __deepcopy__ by calling self.__class__()). 


You would have to remove mapping before creating an instance and then put it back. 


But I have a strong feeling that is not what you actually want to achieve. Don't you just want to have a new instance that can be later put to the sqlalchemy's session but is not related to "original" instance in a sql sense, that is doesn't have it's primary key?

Comment: Well basically, I'm invoking `deepcopy` to make copies of the object and make some changes to those copies. I don't need the SQLA attributes and deepcopying should keep the mapped version intact as well. So is there a way I can invoke `deepcopy` such that I'm only copying everything that, well, doesn't start with `'_'`?

Comment: Well, as long as User class is mapped, every current and new instance of it will have these _sa.* attributes (my previous comment about removing mapper is incorrect).

But why is that a problem exactly? That deep copy is not in sqlalchemy's session and you can modify it any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on deepcopy, but from the error it looks like you need a parameterless constructor to call `self.__class__()` without parameters.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "parameterless constructor"?

Comment: Sorry. An `__init__` which requires no variables beyond self. See zifot's answer for an example.

Comment: What he means is that your User.__init__ function ("constructor", although technically it's not a constructor) takes three arguments: self, user_id and name, but when you're calling self.__class__() you are passing only the first one (implicitly).

Answer (score 0):

To exclude sqlalchemy columns and mapped attributes you would do something along the lines of:

```
for attr in dir(self):
    if not self._sa_class_manager.mapper.has_property(key):
        ...
```