# How to create new instance of current class inside the current class method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class. In method "Complete" i want to make a new instance of this class and add it to the array. But instead it just adds my current instance to the array. How can i create a new instance by using this method?

```
class Task:

    ArrPosition = 0

    def __init__(self, content, state, arr):
        self.content = content
        self.state = state
        self.arr = arr

    def Complete(self, Answer, CurrentPosition):
        if Answer == "True":
            self.state = "True"
            self.ArrPosition += 1
            if self.ArrPosition < 4:
                SessionArray[CurrentPosition + self.arr[self.ArrPosition]].append(Task(self.content, "NULL", [0,2,6,10]))
        if Answer == "False":
            self.state = "True"
            self.ArrPosition = 0
            SessionArray[CurrentPosition + 1].append(Task(self.content, "NULL", [0,2,6,10]))
```

Other examples show how to do that outside of the class description, but i need to do that inside.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create new class instance from class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260557/create-new-class-instance-from-class-method)

Comment: I'm not sure, cause there is a case to create a copy outside of class description, but i need to do that inside

Comment: There's nothing special about creating a new instance from within a method of that class - you're definitely appending new instances of `Task` to your array.  Unfortunately, you haven't given us enough of a [mcve] to be able to tell what's going wrong.  The one thing that looks suspicious in the code you did post is `ArrPosition` - you initialize it as a class attribute, but then override it with an instance attribute, so perhaps it doesn't have the value you expect in the new instance.

Comment: Added a new answer. It helped me:D

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with

```
class Task:

    ArrPosition = 0

    def __init__(self, ArrPosition, content, state, arr):
        self.ArrPosition = ArrPosition
        self.content = content
        self.state = state
        self.arr = arr

    def Clone(self):
        return Task(self.ArrPosition, self.content, "NULL", self.arr)

    def Complete(self, Answer, CurrentPosition):
        if Answer == "True":
            self.state = "True"
            self.ArrPosition += 1
            if self.ArrPosition < 4:
                SessionArray[CurrentPosition + self.arr[self.ArrPosition]].append(Task.Clone(self))
        if Answer == "False":
            self.state = "False"
            self.ArrPosition = 0
            SessionArray[CurrentPosition + 1].append(Task.Clone(self))
```

Answer (score -1):

I checked the script on my console without changing anything and it worked perfectly fine with some arbitrary values chosen for the `Task` constructor, for the arguments of the `Complete` method and for the `SessionArray` variable:

[image]

The cause to your problem could be somwhere else in your code, possibly some erratic input you're feeding it.

Comment: The problem happens when it works on big datasets. I solved it with the method which i've written upper. Thanks!