# How to model special class instances in python

Tags: python

I want to create a class in python that includes class level constants for special instances of the class. i.e. something like this:

```
class Testing:
    SPECIAL = Testing("special")

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


def test_specials():
    norm = Testing("norm")
    assert norm.name == "norm"

    assert Testing.SPECIAL.name == "special"
```

If I try the above code, it fails saying: `NameError: name 'Testing' is not defined`.

How should I model this?

Comment: the `Testing` name isn't available until after the class body is complete -- you'll need to do `Testing.SPECIAL = Testing("special")` after the class body

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create new class instance from class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260557/create-new-class-instance-from-class-method)

Comment: @JohnD, this is a different question: how to set up a class level instance variable rather than how to return a new instance from a class method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Anthony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812183/anthony-sottile) for the answer above. The solution is this:

```
class Testing: 
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

Testing.SPECIAL = Testing("special")

def test_specials():
    norm = Testing("norm")
    assert norm.name == "norm"

    assert Testing.SPECIAL.name == "special"
```