# copy all but one part of an object in python

Tags: python, copy

How would one `copy.deepcopy()` all but one part of an object in python?

I have an object which is basically a wrapper with some settings and some extra bits of metadata around a potentially huge pandas DataFrame. The DataFrame can contain arbitrarily huge amounts of data. I want to make a copy the object that consists of a *shallow copy of the dataframe and a deepcopy() of the settings and metadata* (both of which which can be mutable objects).

*I don't know at run time if all of the settings and metadata exist when the copy is needed*. There is also the possibility to people may set additional parts of the object using `my_object.extra_setting`. This means that I can not just explicitly deepcopy all the parts of the object except the large dataframe.

The class is:

```
    class my_class(object):

        def __init__(self, lots_of_data, small_amount_of_data, setting_1, setting_2, setting_3):
            self.lots_of_data = lots_of_data
            self.small_amount_of_data = small_amount_of_data
            self.setting_1 = setting_1
            self.setting_2 = setting_2

        def set_setting_3(self, setting_3):
            self.setting_3 = setting_3

        def set_more_metadata(metadata):
            self.more_metadata = metadata
```

And in pseudocode the copy method is:

```
        def __deepcopy__(self):

            copy_of_object = copy.deepcopy(self[all but object_in.lots_of_data])
            copy_of_object.lots_of_data = self.lots_of_data

            return copy_of_object
```

Answer (score 3):

your class needs to implement `__deepcopy__()`, which will do the selection of the fields to copy.

Comment: how does one do this? I've looked at the docs but I can't figure it out. I'm probably being stupid but a bit more information would be awesome.

Comment: the implementation looks just like your `copy_my_class` with the only difference that you'd need to explicitly list all the members to copy. there's also a way to select "all but one member" by means of introspection (see e.g. module `inspect`), but I'd recommend to try simple things first.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500718/what-is-the-right-way-to-override-the-copy-deepcopy-operations-on-an-object-in-p

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you're still looking for an answer but I was looking for an answer and this is my solution for anyone

```
import copy
def special_copy_function(object_to_be_copied: my_class) -> my_class:
    memo = {id(object_to_be_copied.lots_of_data): copy.copy(object_to_be_copied.lots_of_data)  # Shallow copy of large data file
    output = copy.deepcopy(object_to_be_copied, memo)  # Deep copy of everything else
    return output
```

`memo` is a dictionary passed to `deepcopy` to help it remember what it has already copied, to avoid copying an item (referenced in several places) multiple times.

By placing a shallow copy of `lots_of_data` in the `memo` dictionary deepcopy will use that value instead of trying to deepcopy `lots_of_data` itself.