# Deep copying a user-defined python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, deep-copy

I have a user defined dictionary (sub-classing python's built-in dict object), which does not allow modifying the dict directly:

```
class customDict(dict):
    """
    This dict does not allow the direct modification of
    its entries(e.g., d['a'] = 5 or del d['a'])
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.update(*args, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self,key,value):
        raise Exception('You cannot directly modify this dictionary. Use set_[property_name] method instead')

    def __delitem__(self,key):
        raise Exception('You cannot directly modify this dictionary. Use set_[property_name] method instead')
```

My problem is that I am not able to deep copy this dictionary using copy.deepcopy. Here's an example:

```
d1 = customDict({'a':1,'b':2,'c':3})
print d1
d2 = deepcopy(d1)
print d2
```

where it throws the exception I've defined myself for setitem:

```
Exception: You cannot directly modify this dictionary. Use set_[property_name] method instead
```

I tried overwriting deepcopy method as follows as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500718/what-is-the-right-way-to-override-the-copy-deepcopy-operations-on-an-object-in-p):

```
def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
    cls = self.__class__
    result = cls.__new__(cls)
    memo[id(self)] = result
    for k, v in self.__dict__.items():
        setattr(result, k, deepcopy(v, memo))
    return result
```

This doesn't throw any errors but it returns an empty dictionary:

```
d1 = customDict({'a':1,'b':2,'c':3})
print d1
d2 = deepcopy(d1)
print d2

{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2} 
{}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Inheritance is probably not a good solution for this.  If your list doesn't do anything that a tuple doesn't already, just use a tuple.  Otherwise use a proxy design pattern ("has a" not "is a")

Comment: Why do you need to deep copy an immutable list?

Comment: Also a good question!  :)

Comment: What you're asking is a legit question! Actually, I first created a user-defined dict that does not allow to directly modify its entries and then did the same for a list forgetting that I can use a tuple instead! I have edited the question and changed the user-defined list to the user-defined dict.

Comment: A related question is how to change the recursion limit for this user-defined deepcopy method when I am redefining deepcopy as "return customDict(deepcopy(dict(self)))". I am using sys.setrecursionlimit(10000) but still get this error: "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded". I don't get this error though when using the other method suggested by 
malbarbo.

Answer (score 2):

Your `deepcopy` implementation does not work because the values of `dict` is not stored in `__dict__`. `dict` is a special class. You can make it work calling `__init__` with a deepcopy of the dict.

```
def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
    def _deepcopy_dict(x, memo):
        y = {}
        memo[id(x)] = y
        for key, value in x.iteritems():
            y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
        return y
    cls = self.__class__
    result = cls.__new__(cls)
    result.__init__(_deepcopy_dict(self, memo))
    memo[id(self)] = result
    for k, v in self.__dict__.items():
        setattr(result, k, deepcopy(v, memo))
    return result
```

This program

```
d1 = customDict({'a': 2,'b': [3, 4]})
d2 = deepcopy(d1)
d2['b'].append(5)

print d1
print d2
```

Outputs

```
{'a': 2, 'b': [3, 4]}
{'a': 2, 'b': [3, 4, 5]}
```

Comment: It looks like `memo` stores the references of the originals, not the copies. Should it be `memo[id(self)] = self`, actually? The first answer to the link in the question also suggests it.

Comment: No. See for example https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/090bbdd8f3debe0b6a6c4aa542937edf250f9443/numpy/ma/core.py#L5852

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for a dictionary. Here's an example: d1 = customDict({'a':2,'b':[3,4]})
d2 = deepcopy(d1)
d2['b'].append(5)
print d1 print d2 {'a': 2, 'b': [3, 4, 5]}
{'a': 2, 'b': [3, 4, 5]}
print d2

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work without having to change deepcopy.

```
x2 = customList(copy.deepcopy(list(x1)))
```

This will cast `x1` to a `list` deepcopy it then make it a `customList` before assigning to `x2`.

Comment: This is a great suggestion! The only thing is that what I am actually deepcopying is a class where this list serves as an instance variable. So, I still have to overwrite the deeopcoopy method. Nevertheless, I I just put: return customList(deepcopy(list(self))) in the definition of the deepcopy and it worked perfectly fine!

Comment: Instead of using customList(deepcopy(list(self))) I am using self.__init__(deepcopy(list(self))). It works fine but the problem that I have is that I get "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded" even though I am using sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

Comment: Why are you calling `__init__()` ? I think when you are calling `self.__init__(deepcopy(list(self)))` you are causing an infinite recursion.

Comment: Sorry, I should have told you that I changed the question from customList to customDict. Like I mentioned in in my first comment, this customDict object that I have serves as an instance attribute of a class. Therefore, I would still need to overwrite the __deepcopy__ method in customDict to be able to deepcopy that class. deepcopy(dict(self)) converts the customDict object to a dictionary and then deepcopies it but then I have to convert it back to customDict and I thought I can do this by self.__init__(deepcopy(dict(self)))

Comment: You should be able to just call `customDict(deepcopy(dict(self)))`

Comment: I get the same error with customDict(deepcopy(dict(self))). I need to emphasize that this does work for simple examples that I tested, but it doesn't work for the actual object that I have. where I always get "maximum recursion depth exceeded" even with customDict(deepcopy(dict(self))) and sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)