# Python - custom deepcopy calling default implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, python-internals

I try to write a custom `deepcopy` that first calls the default implementation, and then does something extra

That is, something like this :

```
class Foo(object):
    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        cp = super(Foo, self).__deepcopy__(memo)
        # custom treatments
        return cp
```

However when I call `deepcopy(Foo())`, I get the following error :

> AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**deepcopy**'

How could I call the default deepcopy from here ?

Comment: What do you mean by *default deepcopy*?

Comment: Yes, if I make a class Bar(object), I can call deepcopy(Bar())

Comment: @Moses, By default implementation I mean rather `cp = deepcopy(self)`, but which leads to a recursive loop

Comment: Why not using `copy.deepcopy(self)`? `object` class do not have any `__deepcopy__()` method

Comment: If anyone's looking for the same thing, with [some ideas from the other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24621200/150015) I could arrive to [a simple solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40484215/150015) to the problem