# copy and deepcopy are changing object type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, copy, deep-copy

I have the following example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from copy import copy, deepcopy

class DataFrameWrapper(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.equals(other)


t1 = DataFrameWrapper(pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3]}))
t2 = deepcopy(t1)
t3 = copy(t1)

print(type(t1), ' ', type(t2), ' ', type(t3))
```

Output:

```
<class 'DataFrameWrapper'>   <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>   <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Is anyone able to tell me why copy and deepcopy are modifying the type of `t1`?

The purpose of the `DataFrameWrapper` class is simply to allow me to do a `==` between pandas DataFrames.

Comment: Why are you call constructor of `DataFrame` twice?

Comment: @OlvinRoght you're right. You can just do `t1 = DataFrameWrapper({'a': [1, 2, 3]})` and get the same issue I indicated in my question

Comment: @Taran Please check my answer, if it helps please upvote and accept.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because copy functionality has been re-defined in pandas to return base type. For your purpose, you can do this:

```
class DataFrameWrapper(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.equals(other)

    def __copy__(self):
        return DataFrameWrapper(super().__copy__())

    def __deepcopy__(self, memo=None):
        return DataFrameWrapper(super().__deepcopy__(memo))
```

OR

```
t1 = DataFrameWrapper(pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3]}))
t2 = DataFrameWrapper(deepcopy(t1))
t3 = DataFrameWrapper(copy(t1))
```

You can refer to [How to override the copy/deepcopy operations for a Python object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500718/how-to-override-the-copy-deepcopy-operations-for-a-python-object) to see how defining __copy__() and __deepcopy()__ works, same as done inside pandas library in pandas/core/generic.py

To test out the above theory (and reproduce the behavior with pandas), here's a test code:

```
from copy import copy, deepcopy

class Base:
    def __copy__(self):
        return Base()

    def __deepcopy__(self, memodict={}):
        return Base()


class Inherited(Base):
    pass


B = Base()
I = Inherited()
I_copy = copy(I)
I_deepcopy = deepcopy(I)

print('Type B :', type(B))
print('Type I :', type(I))
print('Type I_copy :', type(I_copy))
print('Type I_deepcopy :', type(I_deepcopy))
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> Type B : <class '__main__.Base'>
> Type I : <class '__main__.Inherited'>
> Type I_copy : <class '__main__.Base'>
> Type I_deepcopy : <class '__main__.Base'>
> ```