# Deepcopy and iteration return different results

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a 8x8 array that contains objects in some positions, `' '` in others. (It's a chessboard)

My code was running slowly partially due to the use of `copy.deepcopy(x)` so I did some testing and found that iterating through the array was something like 32x faster. When I ran the code it threw errors so I compared the result from the iteration and the `copy.deepcopy(x)` and they aren't the same. I can't see where I'm going wrong or find anything similar (I have looked)

the function is below:

```
def makeCopy(array):
    new = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
    for x in range(0,8):
        for y in range(0,8):
            new[x].append(array[x][y])
    a = copy.deepcopy(array)
    if new != a:
        print('failed')
    else:
        print('good')
    return new
```

When it gets called it prints `failed` so they aren't the same, which breaks the rest of my code.

I'm passing it something like this (some piece positions may differ):

```
currentGameState = [[Rook('black', [0,0]),Knight('black',[1,0]),Bishop('black', [2,0]),Queen('black',[3,0]),King('black',[4,0]),Bishop('black', [5,0]),Knight('black',[6,0]),Rook('black', [7,0])],
                    [Pawn('black', [0,1]),Pawn('black', [1,1]),Pawn('black', [2,1]),Pawn('black', [3,1]),Pawn('black', [4,1]),Pawn('black', [5,1]),Pawn('black', [6,1]),Pawn('black', [7,1])],
                    [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
                    [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
                    [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
                    [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
                    [Pawn('white', [0,6]),Pawn('white', [1,6]),Pawn('white', [2,6]),Pawn('white', [3,6]),Pawn('white', [4,6]),Pawn('white', [5,6]),Pawn('white', [6,6]),Pawn('white', [7,6])],
                    [Rook('white', [0,7]),Knight('white', [1,7]),Bishop('white', [2,7]),Queen('white',[3,7]),King('white',[4,7]),Bishop('white', [5,7]),Knight('white',[6,7]),Rook('white', [7,7])]]
```

Comment: Have you tried `new = list(map(list, array))`?

Comment: @tobias_k just tried it, same issue

Comment: Ok - do these custom classes have `__copy__`/`__deepcopy__`/`__eq__`/`__neq__` methods?

Comment: @hemmelig no - could you point me to some documentation for those? I'm a student who's been given this as a task to keep me occupied - this is my first properly object-oriented program so I'm a little out of my depth

Comment: Is it actually the case that  `a == array`? Maybe your classes `__eq__` method is just broken, so the structure is fine, but the lists are still not "equal".

Comment: @tobias_k I'm fairly sure that the structure is what is broken, when changing from using my ```makeCopy``` function to ```deepcopy``` the rest of the code runs fine, albeit slowly, when using my function it starts crashing all over the place

Comment: Please check `copy.deepcopy(array) == array` anyway. For me your code works fine (substituting the `Rook` classes etc. with simple lists or tuples)

Comment: Look up dunder methods in Python. They are magic methods that can provide a host of additional utility for your classes. `__eq__`, for example, will allow you to use the rich operator `==` to compare between instances of your classes. Also see: [How to override the copy deepcopy operations for a python object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500718/how-to-override-the-copy-deepcopy-operations-for-a-python-object)

Comment: @tobias_k Ok, ```copy.deepcopy(array) == array``` returns ```False```, but I'm not sure why that effects it, for some reason the result of ```copy.deepcopy``` works in my program and the iterative copy doesn't

Comment: Do you actually want to copy the game pieces, too? They seem to include their current position. When you move a piece, do you modify it or create a new one? Still, the basic structure-copying should work fine.

Comment: My guess is: `deepcopy` also copies the game pieces, which is required for your program to work if you modify the pieces (see above comment), and since you probably do not implement `__eq__`, the new instances are not considered equal to their copies (without `__eq__`, `==` just compares memory addresses).

Comment: @tobias_k ok, looks like I do want to be copying the piece objects, how would I do that? use copy.copy or does it have to be deepcopy?

Comment: I think hemmelig and tobias_k have hit on the real problem.  There's nothing wrong with the copying.  The problem is that two objects of the same (user-defined) class with exactly the same data contents don't compare equal unless you provide custom comparison functions.  See [Compare object instances for equality by their attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227121/compare-object-instances-for-equality-by-their-attributes).

Comment: @DennisSparrow I think there has to be a problem with my iterative copy as it's results don't work but deepcopy's do. I think it is because the iterative one doesn't create a new object of the class as tobias_k said.

Comment: Yes, on further investigation, I think that's right, as in the answer from C. Celora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your copy function actually works fine for copying the *structure* of the list, although it could be simplified by using a list comprehension:
`new = [[x for x in row] for row in array]`

The problem, and the difference to `copy.deepcopy` is, though, that it does not copy the actual game pieces like `Rook('black', [0,0])`.
From the various comments, I gather that:

- the pieces do not implement `__eq__`, thus `==` just compares memory addresses and thus your copy is considered "different" from the `deepcopy` (but probably *equal* to the original, and, in fact, the `deepcopy` *different* from the original)
- the pieces include their current position, e.g. `[0,0]`, and you update/modify this position when moving a piece
- thus, when adding the references to the same piece to the copy of the board, your Minimax-algorithm will "move" the pieces in all states, creating lots of invalid game states

Here are a few possible solutions, with increasing complexity of the required refactoring, but also increasing (assumed) benefit:

- add a `copy` function and call that method when creating your "manual" copy, e.g. `new = [[copy(x) for x in row] for row in array]` in my above list comprehension; here, `copy` is not a method, since there are `str` and game pieces in those lists, and `copy` has to work for both (for `str`, it can just return the original, though)
- instead of using that `copy` function each time you copy the state, only create a copy of a game piece just before *moving* that piece, all the other pieces can remain the same; this way, you only have to create one copy instead of 64 per move (you still have to create a copy of the actual board, though)
- drop your `Rook` etc. classes entirely and just use a string representation like `"Rb"` for "black Rook" or a tuple `("Rook", "black")` and do not redundantly include their current position but just take it from the grid itself when calculating possible moves (this would then be a function, not a method of the no-longer-existing class)

The `copy` function used for the first two approaches could e.g. look as simple as this:

```
def copy(piece):
    if isinstance(piece, str):
        return piece
    else:
        return type(piece)(piece.color, list(piece.position))
```

You could also use `copy.deepcopy` on the individual pieces in your loop / list comprehension, which would probably be a bit faster then using it to copy the entire board, but till much slower than a tailored `copy` function.

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually copying the objects inside the matrix.

```
for x in range(0,8):
    for y in range(0,8):
        new[x].append(array[x][y])
```

With this code you're actually binding the same object inside a single cell between the two list of lists. Doing this if you change one object inside the first list's cell it will change the object inside the other list's cell.
That's why it's faster

With copy.deepcopy(array) you copy the cells and also the objects inside each cell.

Python3 copy module:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html

Comment: so deepcopy is my only option here?

Comment: I'm afraid yes. Can i ask what is the purpose of copying the chess board?

Comment: You do not have to use `copy.deepcopy`, though. Just also create a copy of the pieces in your nested loop, in particular creating a new list for the mutable position.

Comment: Making moves to be checked by minimax. the makeMove function gets hit like a million times or something stupid so small gains their speed up minimax hugely. And mskeMove relies on copying, hence me attempting to speed it up

Comment: In this case, do not create fat classes for the game pieces that you probably do not need at all. Instead of `Rook("black", [3,2])`, just use the string `Rb`, or tuple `("Rook", "black")`, and drop the position (do you really need it?)

Comment: @tobias_k sorry, you're going to have to tell me what a fat class is, I've looked it up and can't find it. I think I do need to use the classes as each object has a getMoves() method that relies on its position and colour to search the rest of the board for legal moves

Comment: But it does not have to be a method of the class. You could just have a "static" function that takes a color string, type string, and position (from the grid) and outputs the moves.

Comment: @tobias_k that sounds like a great idea, but it'll require a fairly significant rewrite...

If its the only way to speed it up I'll give it a go

Comment: @user8430559 Alternatively, instead of copying the pieces when copying the board, create a _modified_ copy when _moving_ the pieces. This should be a much smaller change, result in much less copying (one copied piece instead of 64 per move), and you can use your simple list-copy-loop. (Sorry for spamming your answer, I'll stop now.)

Comment: @tobias_k no worries about the spamming, it's really useful. I'm not quite sure what you mean though. Could you post an answer with some form of example code to help me get my head around it? that would probably solve my problem, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When I tried running your code as-is (using np.ones((8, 8)) as the example input), I got:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

because the result of `new != a` is:

```py
[[False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False]]
```

Instead, use:

```py
def makeCopy(array):
    new = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
    for x in range(0,8):
        for y in range(0,8):
            new[x].append(array[x][y])
    a = copy.deepcopy(array)
    if (new != a).any():
        print('failed')
    else:
        print('good')
    return new
```

Here we use `array.any()` to check if any elements in the list (of lists) do not match.

Comment: that just gives me ```AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'any'```

I may not have explained myself properly. I need ```makeCopy(array)``` to return exactly the same value as deepcopy would have, Once it is doing that I'll remove the checks and use the function instead

Comment: Can you provide an example input - I think using a numpy array with shape (8, 8) rather than a list of lists with shape (8, 8) is causing a difference

Comment: Edited the original question

Answer (score 0):

your code prints out 'good' for me, I tried it with integer and with string lists of a list, and returns the correct initial list you give as an argument to the makeCopy function. Are you sure you're using a list of lists to test your function?

Comment: I've edited the original question with what I'm passing ```makeCopy(array)```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please use the comments section to post your suggestions.