# My custom object is not deepcopied when it is used as the default parameter in Pydantic models

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

I know that Pydantic creates a deepcopy of mutable objects for "*every new instances*" that we create, if they are placed in the default values.

It holds true for my `lst` field, but not for my custom object `item`. (The code for `__deepcopy__` is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15774013/13944524))

```py
from copy import deepcopy
from typing import Self

from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict


class Spam:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.names = ["hi"]

    def __deepcopy__(self, memo: dict) -> Self:
        print("deepcopy called")
        cls = self.__class__
        result = cls.__new__(cls)
        memo[id(self)] = result
        for k, v in self.__dict__.items():
            setattr(result, k, deepcopy(v, memo))
        return result


class Person(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(arbitrary_types_allowed=True)

    item: Spam = Spam()
    lst: list = []


print("-----------------------------------")

obj1 = Person()
obj2 = Person()

obj1.lst.append(10)
obj1.item.names.append("bye")

print(obj1.lst)
print(obj1.item.names)
print(obj2.lst)
print(obj2.item.names)
print(id(obj1.item) == id(obj2.item))
```

output:

```
deepcopy called
-----------------------------------
[10]
['hi', 'bye']
[]
['hi', 'bye']
True
```

I printed the dashed-line after creating the class and before any instantiation just to show that the deepcopy of my object is indeed happened in class creation which is in contrast to the [documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/models/#fields-with-non-hashable-default-values):

> Pydantic will deepcopy the default value when creating each instance of the model

Do I miss something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works only for not hashable objects, but according to Python documentation

> Objects which are instances of user-defined classes are hashable by
> default

https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable

(I was also surprised)

So, you can use `default_factory` to achieve your goal:

```
from copy import deepcopy

from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict, Field


class Spam:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.names = ["hi"]

    # def __deepcopy__(self, memo: dict):
    #     print("deepcopy called")
    #     cls = self.__class__
    #     result = cls.__new__(cls)
    #     memo[id(self)] = result
    #     for k, v in self.__dict__.items():
    #         setattr(result, k, deepcopy(v, memo))
    #     return result


class Person(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(arbitrary_types_allowed=True)

    item: Spam = Field(default_factory=Spam)
    lst: list = []


print("-----------------------------------")

obj1 = Person()
obj2 = Person()

obj1.lst.append(10)
obj1.item.names.append("bye")

print(obj1.lst)
print(obj1.item.names)
print(obj2.lst)
print(obj2.item.names)
print(id(obj1.item) == id(obj2.item))
```

Comment: Oh right. "not hashable objects" was the key. If I implement `__eq__` in my `Spam` class, everything works as expected. I was aware of `default_factory`, my question was about the reason of why this is happening.