# Why does python not support ++i or i++

Tags: python, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why there are no ++ and — operators in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654830/why-there-are-no-and-operators-in-python)

`++i` is legal. But it's the unary + operator.

And `i++` is illegal.

Why Python decides not support the `++` operator in normal way?

Comment: What sort of answer are you expecting to this question? Doesn't it require one of the people who worked on it to come round and explain the thinking?

Comment: Define "normal". Why do you need `i++` if `i += 1` does the job?

Comment: @louxiu I admit it's hard to search for `++` and `--` :-)

Comment: @DominicKexel Yeah... I tried to search it. :-)

Comment: Terminology: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators