# Variables in python right use

Tags: variables

Given variables `a`, `b`:

```
b = 3

a = b++

a = --b
```

How do you write this correctly in Python?

Comment: In python a statement doesn't return anything. also `b++` is invalid in python.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654830/why-are-there-no-and-operators-in-python

Answer (score 10):

From [The Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> Explicit is better than implicit

So, let's write:

```
b = 3
a = b; b +=1
b -= 1; a = b
```

Answer (score 5):

There are no increment/decrement (`++`/`--`) operators in Python. This is because integers in Python are **immutable** (can't be modified, only reassigned). So let's break this down and emulate their behavior.

What does `b++` do? It evaluates to `b`, then increments `b`. Therefore, we write this as:

```
a = b
b += 1
```

Now onto `--b`. It decrements `b`, then evaluates to the new value of `b`. In Python:

```
b -= 1
a = b
```

Put it all together and we get:

```
b = 3
a = b
b += 1
b -= 1
a = b
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python, you cannot do `b++`. There is no plus plus.

There is the operator `+=`, so you could this kind of stuff:

```
b = 3

b += 1

b -= 1
```

Or simply:

```
b = 3

a = b + 1

a = b - 1
```