# Python, -1 return value

Tags: python

So guys, I have a funky error going on and I'm wondering if you could help me out.
I have a function that's supposed to find the way to give change using the least coins.

```
def change_counter(cost, paid):
    changefor = paid - cost
```

and i have a a variable, changefor which is basically how much money you need to make change for.
Then I declared some variables, penny = 0 and such that track how many of each coin are being given out.
Then I made a while loop, that cycles until changefor hits zero.

```
while(changefor > 0):
    if changefor >= 100:
        changefor - 100
        ++hundreddollar
    elif,etc
```

The rest is really self explanatory, and just printing the amounts of each coin used, etc. Does anyone see what could be causing a problem? I get a return value of -1, and nothing from the while loop seems to be doing anything.

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll definitely read that but do you have any idea what could be causing an error from the code I posted?

Comment: Not sure.. if you throw me a gist on the whole script i will tell you why ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Because you're computing things but not storing them anywhere**

First, thank you for teaching me something new.

```
++x
```

*does* compile, and also *does* nothing. Look here, [Why are there no ++ and --​ operators in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654830/why-are-there-no-and-operators-in-python), but there are no increment/decrement operators in python. Similarly,

```
changefor - 100
```

Doesn't do anything. Sure, it evaluates `changefor` and subtracts 100, but then it doesn't store that value anywhere. Pitfall of a dynamic language.

```
changefor = changefor - 100
```

or

```
changefor -= 100
```

will do you better

Edit: I was about to ask why the decrement syntax is accepted and found that this person [Behaviour of increment and decrement operators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485841/behaviour-of-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-python) already ran into this oddity.

Comment: You beat me to this - I was trying to figure out what on earth this was doing.