# Create tuple list of key,val from another list of values in Python

Tags: python

I have the following python list in

```
[0,1,2,'def','ghi']
```

Now I want to convert above into another list of tuples by discarding first list item so for e.g. I want `[(1,0),(2,1),('def',2),('ghi',3)]`

I have the following code

```
point = [0,1,2,'def','ghi']
spliltm0 = split[1:]
ls = ()
int i = 0
for a in spliltm0:
   ls = (a,i++)
```

The above seems to be long code for Python, is there any shorter version of above code? I am super new to Python.

Comment: `strip()` on a list? Also `[(j,i) for i,j in enumerate(point[1:])]`

Comment: Sorry it was typo please see edited question

Comment: I am a beginner in python I mentioned in the question down voters care to tell the reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code isn't Python at all, since you do `int i` and `i++`, neither of which are Python*; also, `strip()` and `split()` are methods on strings, not lists.

Your result can be achieved in a one-line list comprehension:

```
result = [(elem, i) for i, elem in enumerate(point[1:])]
```

---

<sub>* `i++` is syntactically valid in Python, but doesn't at all do what you think it does.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You need to be clear about the basics of Python before asking in the Python Forum.

1) You cannot apply strip function on a 'list' object, It should be string object.

2) `spliltm0 = split[1:]`, Here split is treated as string, and is not defined. Also split is a string method which should not be used as a variable for storing string.

3) `int i = 0` This is a format of C/C++. Not applicable to Python

4)

```
for a in spliltm0:
   ls = (a,i++)
```

i++ is not available in Python. Refer to this link ([Why are there no ++ and --​ operators in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654830/why-are-there-no-and-operators-in-python))

Comment: str.split is a str method not a builtin function