# Assignment within expression in Python

Tags: python, syntax

In Java, if I want to increase a variable A, and set B equal to C, I can do it one statement as follows:

`B = C + A - A++;`

Python, unfortunately, does not support assignment within literals. What is the best way to mimic this kind of behavior within the language of Python? (with the intention of writing code in as few statements as possible)

Let me set something straight: **I am not interested in writing code that is readable.** I am interested in writing code with as few statements as possible.

One trivial example of one case where this would work would be to write a `class` that holds an `int` and has methods such as `plus_equals`, `increment`, etc.

Comment: You can't. Python won't let you (thankfully).

Comment: Python is not interested in helping you write code that isn't readable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654830/why-are-there-no-and-operators-in-python

Comment: *"Python, unfortunately, does not support assignment within literals"* - huh? Nothing in your example Java code is a literal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the global namespace, you can do something **really ugly** like this:

```
B = globals().__setitem__('A', A + 1) or C
```

Unfortunately for you (and probably fortunately for the person who has to read the code after you've written it), there is no analogous way to do this with a local variable `A`.

Comment: I hope you use this power [responsibly](http://preshing.com/20110926/high-resolution-mandelbrot-in-obfuscated-python/) . . .

Comment: I absolutely love this solution. Thank you

Comment: Gross. Please don't do this

Comment: @ChadS. -- I completely agree that this code should never be used except for novel experiments like the mandelbrot set code that I linked or code-golf-like competitions where the normal "rules" don't apply ...

Answer (score -1):

> Let me set something straight: **I am not interested in writing code that is readable.** I am interested in writing code with as few statements as possible.

Well, if that's your goal, wrap your entire program in a giant `exec`:

```
exec """
<your program here>
"""
```

Bam, one statement.