# Why print(a++) has syntax errors in python, but not print(++a)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner in python and I am using Python 3.5. The python console complains invalid syntax for the below statement:

```
a = 5
print(a++)
```

But `print(++a)` works fine. Can anyone help me understand the difference?
Btw, it seems that `print(a+=1)` also doesn't work.
Thanks!

Comment: And just for added information about why there is no support for `++` and `--`, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654830/why-are-there-no-and-operators-in-python)

Answer (score 7):

- `++a` is just the same as doing (+(+a)). I.E: You're using the mathematical addition operator on the variable `a` (with implied zeroes). So the result is `a`
- `a++` is not valid python syntax (unlike other languages).
- `a += 1` is an assignment. It is equivalent to `a = a + 1` - you can not print an assignment