# Insert obj into a list once

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I wrote a function that is supposed to insert a 2D list into a table.

This is the code:

```
seats_plan = [[True, True, True, True, True], [True, True, True, True, True], [True, True, True, True, True], [True, True, True, True, True], [True, True, True, True, True]]
def print_database(seats_plan):
    for row in seats_plan:
        row.insert(0, seats_plan.index(row))
    seats_plan.insert(0, [' ', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4'])
    for k in seats_plan:
        for char in k:
           if char is True:
               print '.',
           elif char is False:
               print 'x',
           else:
               print char,
        print
```

and the output is:

```
  0 1 2 3 4
0 . . . . .
1 . . . . .
2 . . . . .
3 . . . . .
4 . . . . .
```

but it also changed `seats_plan`, so if I call the function again it inserts the numbers again.
How can I make it insert it only once without changing the original `seats_plan`?

Comment: You should create a *copy* of the list and modify that, rather than the original.

Comment: You want a function that inserts things into a table the first time it is called, but not the second?

Answer (score 1):

Don't change the list, because it is only a reference, e.g. the same as the original list. Print the numbers, when needed:

```
seats_plan = [[True, True, True, True, True], [True, True, True, True, True], [True, True, True, True, True], [True, True, True, True, True], [True, True, True, True, True]]
def print_database(seats_plan):
    print ' ', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4'
    for row, seats in enumerate(seats_plan):
        print row,
        for seat in seats:
            print '.' if seat else 'x',
        print
```

or with list comprehension

```
def print_database(seats_plan):
    plan = [ '%d %s' % (row, ' '.join('.' if seat else 'x' for seat in seats))
        for row, seats in enumerate(seats_plan)]
    plan.insert(0, '  ' + ' '.join(str(c) for c in range(len(seats))))
    print '\n'.join(plan)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you an expectation that Python is passing by value, but Python always references. Consider this SO post: [Emulating pass-by-value...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845110/emulating-pass-by-value-behaviour-in-python)

You can create a copy in your first couple lines with:

```
from copy import deepcopy
def print_database(seats_plan):
    seats_plan_copy = deepcopy(seats_plan)
```

Comment: Just to be clear, Python passes references, which is different than "pass by reference", which allows functions to reassign names in the caller's namespace.

Comment: @NedBatchelder, I edited the answer as you described.