# Python why data are mutually updated when I perform operations?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python. I wanted to try some simple function operations on dataframe but I encountered the following problem. My code is:

```
>>> df.head(3)
   PercChange
0    0.000000
1   -7.400653
2    2.176843
>>> def switch(array):
...     for i in range(len(array)):
...         if array[i]<0:
...             array[i]=0
...     return array
... 
>>> a=df.PercChange
>>> a=switch(a)
>>> df['PosPercChange']=a
>>> df.head(3)
   PercChange  PosPercChange
0    0.000000       0.000000
1    0.000000       0.000000
2    2.176843       2.176843
```

Why did my 'PercChange' column change as well? I already created a new variable for the operations separately. How can I avoid not changing my 'PercChange' column? Thanks a lot.

[Solved]

So it is the problem of the data structure. In Python, '=' assignment doesn't copy value from one to another, but instead it name the same sequence with different name so changing one also changes the other. Thanks for the help.

Comment: When you assign a value to a variable in Python, it doesn't copy the value; the variable just becomes a new name for the same value. So, `a` and `df.PercChange` are the exact same `Series`., and a change to one affects the other. If you want to make a copy, you have to say so explicitly. Pandas, Numpy, and other libraries have specific ways to do different kinds of copying, while the `copy` module in the stdlib has the general functions `copy.copy` and `copy.deepcopy`; you have to decide what exactly you want in each case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emulating pass-by-value behaviour in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845110/emulating-pass-by-value-behaviour-in-python)

Comment: You created a new *name* that is a pointer to the same object. So now you have two "variables" (names) referring to the same underlying object in memory. A change to one of them changes "both" variables, because they both point to the same *thing*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign a value to a variable in Python, it doesn't copy the value; the variable just becomes a new name for the same value.

So, `a` and `df.PercChange` are just different names for the exact same `Series`. The same way a change to "Star Wars V" affects "The Empire Strikes Back" or a change to "Former President George W. Bush" affects "President Bush 42", a change to `a` affects `df.PercChange`.

And calling a function is just assignment again: the parameter inside the function becomes another name for the same value as the argument in the function call, so `array` is the same object as `a` and `df.PercChange`.

If you want to make `a` into a name for a *copy* of the *same data* as `df.PercChange`, instead of a name for the same object, you have to ask for that copy explicitly.

---

With Pandas, this is usually just the [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.copy.html) method:

```
a = df.PercChange.copy()
```

But Pandas (and the NumPy library that underlies it) allows for all kinds of complicated things, so there are other complicated ways to copy things.

---

More generally, Python has the [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) module, with `copy` and `deepcopy` functions that can make shallow or deep copies of almost anything, not just Pandas Series.

---

But you're also halfway to a different solution. Your `switch` function does a `return array` at the end, and your caller does `a = switch(a)`.

If `switch` returned a *different* object, `a` would now be a name for that different object. But, because it instead just returns its parameter, after modifying it in-place, all that `a = switch(a)` is doing is re-asserting `a` as a name for the same value it's already a name for.

So, another way to fix things is to do the copying inside `switch`:

```
def switch(array):
    array = array.copy()
    for i in range(len(array)):
        if array[i]<0:
            array[i]=0
    return array
```

… or to build up a whole new array or Series and return that:

```
def switch(array):
    return array.apply(lambda: 0 if x<0 else x)
```