# how to assign new array instead of build pointer in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, reference, pass-by-reference

In below code, I expect to get :

```
[[1, 4, 6], [2, 3, 6], [2, 4, 5]]
```

But it return :

```
[[1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 5]]
```

There are two problems :

- word in function b is a reference, not a new variable!!
- everything put in the child is a reference!!

My code :

```
def b(word,i):
    word[i] = word[i]-1
    return word
def a(individual):
    child = []
    for i in range(len(individual)):
        child.append(b(individual,i))
    return child
print(a([2,4,6,8]))
```

Comment: You already answered to your own question. You need to passby value: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845110/emulating-pass-by-value-behaviour-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your `b` function to this:

```
def b(word,i):
    tmp = word.copy()
    tmp[i] = tmp[i]-1
    return tmp
```

Because when you actually change the `individual` list it will be change all over the program, I mean your code is write but when you change `2` to `1` it changes all over the program. for better understanding add a `print('child')` after the append.