# Questions about In-place memory operations in pandas (1/2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I was explaining<sup>[1]</sup> in-place operations vs out-of-place operations to a new user of Pandas. This resulted in us discussing passing objects by reference of by value.

Naturally, I wanted to show `pandas.DataFrame.values` as I thought it shared the memory location of the underlying data of the DataFrame. However, I was surprised with and then sidetracked by the results of the following code segment.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3,4],
                   'y': [5,4,3,2]})
print(df)
df.values += 1 # raises AttributeError
```

```py
   x  y
0  1  5
1  2  4
2  3  3
3  4  2
<ipython-input-126-9fa9f393972b>:8: UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name - see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access
  df.values += 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __setattr__(self, name, value)
   5169                 else:
-> 5170                     object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
   5171             except (AttributeError, TypeError):

AttributeError: can't set attribute

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-126-9fa9f393972b> in <module>
      6 print(df)
      7 
----> 8 df.values += 1

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __setattr__(self, name, value)
   5178                         stacklevel=2,
   5179                     )
-> 5180                 object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
   5181 
   5182     def _dir_additions(self):

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

However, despite this error, if we re-examine the df, it has changed.

```py
print(df)
```

```py
  x  y
0  2  6
1  3  5
2  4  4
3  5  3
```

### My attempt to explain this behavior.

First, we can write `df.values += 1` as `df.values = df.values.__iadd__(1)`

That means the RHS of this expression evaluates properly resulting in the underlying data being changed. Then, re-assigning `df.values` to a new value raises the exception.

If I break up these two operations, no error is raised and the underlying data is changed.

```py
print(df)

values = df.values

values += 1

print(df)
```

```py
   x  y
0  2  6
1  3  5
2  4  4
3  5  3
   x  y
0  3  7
1  4  6
2  5  5
3  6  4
```

### Is this a bug?

#### Should `.values` be treated differently than with `__getattr__/__setattr__`?

Part of me wants to say this is not a bug as the user should read the documentation and use the recommend replacement [pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy).

However, part of me says that it is pretty unintuitive to see a "AttributeError: can't set attribute" but have the underlying operation actually work. That being said, I can't think of a solution that allows these operations to work in the proper situations while still preventing improper use.

Does anyone have any insights into this?

[1]: Until I got derailed by this issue and [Insert Link] potential issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass-by-value vs. pass-by-reference in Python is a knotty topic, see [Emulating pass-by-value behaviour in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845110/emulating-pass-by-value-behaviour-in-python) and also read the comments under the question

This is the 'state of the art' :

> Not quite. **Python passes arguments neither by reference nor by value,
> but by assignment**.

source : **https://realpython.com/python-pass-by-reference/**

Similar is in **https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-by-reference-vs-value-in-python/**

Outgoing from this i think this behavior is not a bug but it is in a grey zone. This behavior is in my opinion rooted in the linking between Pandas and Numpy. `df.values` returns a numpy representation (an array) of the dataframe ( https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html ) call it `a` and `a+1` is valid syntax for increasing an entire numpy array (https://scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/operations.html). On the other hand according to the error message, *Pandas* [!] does not allow new columns to be created via a new attribute. This error message emerges from the re-assignment step in `df.values =+1`, the re-assignment is in `df.values = df.values+1` : `df.values` is a numpy array that is increased by `df.values+1` (what is valid syntax).

Then this numpy array is re-assigned to its pandas dataframe representation by `df.values=df.values+1` what throws the known error message. This step is only allowed to work because it alters the same memory location, the same object. So it is not essentially a bug however it is also not purely white but grey instead...